# Find all properties of an ActiveX component

Tags: c#, properties, com, activex, idispatch

I tried looking around but was not able to convince myself with an answer as the world of COM/ActiveX seems to be very confusing.
Basically what I want to know is, given the GUID, is there a way to know all the interfaces, properties and methods exposed by an ActiveX control? 
I read somewhere that you just have to ask if a particular property is there or not. But how do I ask about a property before knowing what are there?
I guess IDispatch does something similar, but I am not able to make out how to use it. If this is the one that works, a small snippet, preferably in C# would help me understand better.

Thanks

Answer (score 6):

You can use PowerShell for this:

```
$a = new-object -comobject ProgId
#get properties
$a | Get-Member -membertype properties 
#or get all members
$a | Get-Member
```

And in C# you can use [Type.GetMembers Method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.type.getmembers(v=vs.110).aspx).

Answer (score 0):

ActiveX controls don't have to be self-descriptive and be capable to enumerate supported interfaces and/or properties. As other COM classes they implement certain interfaces and being implementing a certain set of mandatory interfaces they are good for embedding into host application. That is, you might end up being unable to find properties for a certain valid ActiveX Control.

Quite so often though, you can succeed with this tasks if given control does what most of controls do. Control's COM Class typically has a typelibrary you can discover by looking at registry reference, or [`IProvideClassInfo`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms687303%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) interface. From there on when you hold `ITypeInfo` interface, you can locate `IDispatch` derived interfaces of the class, and then enumerate properties and method using the type library, which holds this information.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [OLE/COM Object Viewer](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms688269%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) in Microsoft's Resource Toolkit. That will list all properties/methods/events/etc.